# Spring Integration added X-* to Custom Headers when the header used for header value routing

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using header value router and in the final webservice, the header that used for header value routing is appended with a X-* String.

The Spring Integration router snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd">

<bean id="byteArrayHttpMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter">
</bean>

<bean id="formHttpMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter">
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

<bean id="headerMapper"
class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
   <property name="inboundHeaderNames" value="*" />
   <property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="*" />
   <property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value="" />
</bean>

<int:channel id="http.request.submit.withfiles" />
<int:channel id="http.response.submit.withfiles" />

<int:channel id="http.router.route1.process.submit.withfiles" />
<int:channel id="http.router.route2.process.submit.withfiles" />

<int-http:inbound-gateway id="http.gateway.inbound.submit.withfiles"
   supported-methods="POST" header-mapper="headerMapper" 
   request-channel="http.request.submit.withfiles"
   reply-channel="http.response.submit.withfiles" path="/v1.0/file">
   <int-http:request-mapping consumes="multipart/form-data"
      produces="application/json" />
   <int-http:header name="routingCode" expression="headers['routingCode']" />

</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:header-value-router input-channel="http.request.submit.withfiles"
header-name="routingCode" default-output- 
channel="http.router.route2.process.submit.withfiles">
<int:mapping value="AB"
    channel="http.router.route1.process.submit.withfiles" />
<int:mapping value="AC"
    channel="http.router.route2.process.submit.withfiles" />
</int:header-value-router>

<int-http:outbound-gateway
id="http.gateway.outbound.route1.submit.withfiles" header-mapper="headerMapper"
   request-channel="http.router.route1.process.submit.withfiles"
   reply-channel="http.response.submit.withfiles"
   url="http://localhost:8080/myapplication1/file"
   http-method-expression="headers.http_requestMethod"
   expected-response-type="java.lang.String" charset="UTF-8" 
reply-timeout="50000" />
```

The captured header is as below:

```
GET /mapfre-tron-mobile/badgeCounters HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
X-*routingCode: AB
X-*http_requestMethod: GET
X-*errorChannel:     org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@c52014
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ml;q=0.6
authorization: 43c3a826-eef1-42f7-af80-e017964ca158
X-*replyChannel: org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@c52014
X-*http_requestUrl: http://localhost:8080/my-switcher/v1.0/file
content-type: application/json
X-*id: 1b24823e-0d07-1225-aead-b80f3a8691b1
Cache-Control: no-cache
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36
X-*timestamp: 1443145971493
Pragma: no-cache
Host: localhost:8081
Connection: keep-alive
```

As you can see, I am passing routingCode as a header, but it is become X-*routingCode:.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show your `headerMapper` bean, but it looks like you are mapping all headers; this is not likely correct (e.g. `replyChannel`), you should be more specific as to which headers are being mapped.

The `*` in the `X-*...` headers looks weird - I am guessing there is some other bad mapping configuration.

If you don't want a prefix (`X-` is a common prefix for custom HTTP headers), you can suppress it in the header mapper.

Please add your header mapper configuration to the question as well as any other relevant upstream configuration.

As always, DEBUG logging will generally help with situations like this.

Comment: Gary, Thanks for the attention. As you see I updated the full route xml. I just want to mention, I am passing 2 headers - authorization and routeCode. The problem is occurred only to routeCode which is used for header value routing and authorization is coming without any issues.

Comment: It's not obvious what's happening; I'd need to see a DEBUG log. However, as I said, mapping all headers `"*"` on both inbound and outbound HTTP adapters is rather unusual. It's also unusual to use the same mapper on both inbound and outbound gateways. Try mapping `"HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, authorization,routeCode"` on the outbound gateway. Also, take a look at a DEBUG log and post it someplace if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Resolved. I have many SI route config file which are imported in one single file. In one of the route file,  I had the configuration like <bean id="headerMapper"
  class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
  <property name="inboundHeaderNames" value="*" />
  <property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="*" />
  <property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value="X-*" />
 </bean>. So I changed the bean from headerMapper to headerMapper1.